# Relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, compiler-errors

I’ve been trying to recompile with `-fPIC`, but it seems I am getting the same error. Am I doing it right or am I missing something else?

```
all: pr1 pr2

pr1:
    g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -c $(wildcard pr1.cpp)
    g++ -std=c++11 -o $(PROGRAM) pr1.o $(LIBRARY) $(LINKER_FLAGS)
    rm -f pr1.o
pr2:
    g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -c $(wildcard pr2.cpp)
    g++ -std=c++11 -o $(PROGRAM1) pr2.o $(LIBRARY) $(LINKER_FLAGS)
    rm -f pr2.o
```

The problem seems to occur at the second program (pr2), possibly when I am trying to reuse LIBRARY(.a file).

Comment: This error can be stably got if compile objects with clang but link with gcc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was not removing the *.a* library that was produced. Use `make clean` first.